# Why isnt my WPF menuItem Icon showing?

Tags: c#, wpf

I can see my Icon in Designer View, but when I run the program it disappears. What am i missing?

EDIT: The Icon itself is 25 by 25 pixels

[image]

```
<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="Transparent">
        <MenuItem Header="Help">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Image Source="Resources/Help.png" />
            </MenuItem.Icon>
            <MenuItem Header="About" />
            <MenuItem Header="Update TechTools" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set properties on your `Help.png` file. Righ-click on it, select properties. You want `Build action` to "Content" and `Copy to output directory` either Copy Always or Copy if Newer.

You can also consider setting it as Resource, which will embedd it in the program itself.